# What is a framework in PHP?

Tags: php, frameworks

How does one determine if a certain PHP project has evolved to the point that it's a framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As soon as it's possible to develop two different projects using it as a common base.

Strictly speaking, a single class you use in several projects is already a (small) framework.

Answer (score 2):

> A web application framework is a
>   software framework that is designed to
>   support the development of dynamic
>   websites, Web applications and Web
>   services. The framework aims to
>   alleviate the overhead associated with
>   common activities performed in Web
>   development. For example, many
>   frameworks provide libraries for
>   database  access, templating
>   frameworks and session management, and
>   they often promote code reuse.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_framework

> How does one determine if a certain
>   PHP project has evolved to the point
>   that it's a framework?

If the project has evolved into above definition, it is a framework but mostly frameworks are made on their own.

To put it simply, a framework is an skeleton on which projects are made.

Answer (score 1):

By their own sense. Framework is not "something big and thrilling".
But just a toolbox.